# SQL Query to fetch maximum 'AnswerTimeStamp' for each unique 'UserId' and 'TrainingId' from the provided table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table data is as below:**

[image: image description]

**Requirements**

To fetch only the highlighted rows from the above table since the other rows has the same `UserId` and `TrainingId`.

Please let me know if more stuffs is required to support the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with the following approach:

```
SELECT 
   UserID, TrainingId, AnswerTimeStamp
FROM (
   SELECT
      UserID, TrainingId, AnswerTimeStamp,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, TrainingId ORDER BY AnswerTimeStamp DESC) AS Rn
) t
WHERE t.Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct userid,trainingid,MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY userid,trainingid) 
from test;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple aggregation as per sample data :

```
select  UserID, TrainingId, max(AnswerTimeStamp)
from table t
group by UserID, TrainingId;
```